# Find rank of user by LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, ranking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODIvr.jpg)
How can I get Rank of a user in table by LINQ ? I use VB.NET CODE

if we have these fields in our table

[id , name , score]

after order by score of users how we can get the ranking ( row number ) one of them in our query ?

Comment: LING?  Sounds awesome.  I wanna get a box of that

Comment: You wouldn't use LINQ for that.

Comment: When you have two records with the same score, how do you determine what the score is? In your example, you have `"A1"` & `"A7"` with the same score of `7`, but `"A1"` has rank `3` and `"A7"` has rank 4. Normally with ranking systems they both share `3` and the ranking would skip straight to `5` for the next one. How do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you man . I used the bellow code and it's work fine for me:

```
        Dim query = (From P In DB.tblUserScores Order By P.Score
                                           Descending Select P).AsEnumerable()

        Dim Rank As Integer = 1
        For Each userObj As tblUserScore In query
            If userObj.DeviceId = DeviceID Then Exit For
            Rank += 1
        Next
```

Comment: Yes it is better way but I think it should return Rank = 5 ( because A1 & A7 both have 7 Score ) how can we solve this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
Dim records = _
{ _
    New With { Key .ID = 1, Key .Name = "A1", Key .Score = 7 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 2, Key .Name = "A2", Key .Score = 9 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 3, Key .Name = "A3", Key .Score = 2 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 4, Key .Name = "A4", Key .Score = 1 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 5, Key .Name = "A5", Key .Score = 6 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 6, Key .Name = "A6", Key .Score = 4 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 7, Key .Name = "A7", Key .Score = 7 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 8, Key .Name = "A8", Key .Score = 3 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 9, Key .Name = "A9", Key .Score = 5 }, _
    New With { Key .ID = 10, Key .Name = "A10", Key .Score = 8 } _
}

Dim query = _
    From r In Records _
    Order By r.Name Ascending
    Order By r.Score Descending
    Select r

query.Dump()

Dim rank = _
    query _
        .Select(Function (x, n) New With { Key .Record = x, Key .Rank = n + 1 }) _
        .ToDictionary(Function (x) x.Record.Name, Function (x) x.Rank)

Dim name = "A9"
Console.WriteLine("User " & name & "'s Rank is " & rank(name))
```

That gives me:

```
User A9's Rank is 6
```